# Why are some rows missing from the result set when two tables are inner joined

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

my query is not displaying entire zero row.
 i mean.. in my output there  were some rows, whose output is zero among all the columns. that particular rows were not displayed in my output.
i want even zero rows to in my output

i'm getting the output like this

```
    abc  1  2  3 
    def  4  5  6
    xyz  2  5  4
    mng  2  5  6
```

but the actual output i needed is

```
    abc  1  2  3 
    def  4  5  6
    ghf  0  0  0
    xyz  2  5  4
    mng  2  5  6
    jkl  0  0  0
```

Row containing zeros is being eliminated.

i'm using joins between two tables.. the first column i'm using as group by phase.
the rest of the columns are result of sum of..

the reason for zeros in the output is, i don't have data for those names in the secondary table.. there exists no data..but i want to display as zeros instead of missing out the entire column.

Here is the query which i used.....

```
SELECT 
    [ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I as 'Types'
    ,sum(CASE when [TECH_V].[CLOS_T]='N4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'N4'
    ,SUM(CASE when [TECH_V].[CLOS_T]='N3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'N3'
    ,SUM(CASE when [TECH_V].[CLOS_T]='N2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'N2'
FROM [supt_oper_anls_dw].[dbo].[TECH_V] as [TECH_V]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [supt_oper_anls_dw].[dbo].ACCT_DATE_DIM AS [ASACCT] 
    ON CONVERT(varchar(10),[ASACCT].GREG_D, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(10), [TECH_V].[OPEN_TS], 101)
WHERE 
    [TECH_INCDT_V].[KGRP_I] ='73fd71ecf84f5080217683869fd819c3'
    and ((
            [ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I >(datepart(MONTH,getdate()))-1-6 
            and [ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I <=(datepart (MONTH,getdate()))-1 
            and [ASACCT].ACCT_YR_I = (datepart(year,getdate()))
        )
        or (
            [ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I>(datepart(MONTH,getdate()))-6-1+12 
            and [ASACCT].ACCT_YR_I = (datepart(year,getdate()))-1
        ))
    and [TECH_V].Notes like '%MFTFD%'
    and [TECH_V].notes like '%DEV%'
group by 
    [ASACCT].ACCT_MO_I,[ASACCT].ACCT_YR_I
```

Comment: Please post your table structure, some sample data and the current query that you are using.

Comment: USE a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to start with. That will include the missing rows, which will be shown with `null` values. Add `ISNULL` function to your columns to show 0 when the value is `null`.

Comment: Here is the query im using

Comment: SELECT 
*
FROM [dw].[dbo].[TECH_V] as [TECH_V]
right outer JOIN [dw].[dbo].ACCT_DATE_DIM AS [ASACCT] ON CONVERT(varchar(10), [TECH__V].[OPEN_TS], 101)=CONVERT(varchar(10), [ASACCT].GREG_D, 101) 
WHERE [TECH_V].[WKGRP_I] ='73fd71ecf84f5080217683869fd819c3'
and [ASACCT].MO=10
and [ASACCT].YR=2012
and [TECH_V].Notes like '%MSTR%'
and [TECH_V].Notes like '%DEV%'

Comment: this query is not displaying any row at all

Comment: That query is missing the sum and group by described earlier. Please post your complete query, and _edit it into the original question_.

Comment: i modified the code..can youverify why it is not populating the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use left or right join
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM [dw].[dbo].[TECH_V] as [TECH_V] right outer JOIN [dw].[dbo].ACCT_DATE_DIM AS [ASACCT] ON CONVERT(varchar(10), [TECH__V].[OPEN_TS], 101)=CONVERT(varchar(10), [ASACCT].GREG_D, 101) WHERE [TECH_V].[WKGRP_I] ='73fd71ecf84f5080217683869fd819c3' and [ASACCT].MO=10 and [ASACCT].YR=2012 and [TECH_V].Notes like '%MSTR%' and [TECH_V].Notes like '%DEV%'

Answer (score 0):

Try a `LEFT JOIN` in your query. If you do `A LEFT JOIN B` then everything from `A` will be in the results. Try this

```
create table #a_table 
( a int)
insert into #a_table
values
( 100),
( 200),
( 300),
( 400)

create table #b_table 
( b int)
insert into #b_table
values
( 100),
( 200),
( 300),
( 600),
( 700),
( 900)

--inner join
select * 
from   #a_table a
    inner join #b_table b
        on a.a = b.b

--left outer join   
select * 
from   #a_table a
       left outer join #b_table b
        on a.a = b.b
```

Then try to comment out various parts of your query to see if other sections of the script are limiting what is being returned.

I suspect if you comment out most of the `WHERE` clause then the rows you want will be in the result set.

In my simplified example I can add in the following `WHERE` clause....

```
select * 
from   #a_table a
       left outer join #b_table b
        on a.a = b.b
where b.b >10
```

...the row has now gone from the results. So now you'd need to start applying either the `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` function...

```
select * 
from   #a_table a
       left outer join #b_table b
        on a.a = b.b
where ISNULL(b.b,11) >10
```

Comment: @nitish did this help at all?